# Stream "File is open in another program"

Tags: c#, stream

i can't find some error in this code 
every check gave me this error " File is open in another program"
i think there is some stream i haven't dispose

```
public static void CheckResolution(string imagePath)
{                
    var image = LoadSigleImageFromFile(imagePath);
    var baseArea = 2600 * 1000;//dimenzioni in risoluzione 
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(image.FileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    try
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);

        var imageArea = img.Height * img.Width;
        if (imageArea >= baseArea)
        {
            var scaleFactor = (imageArea / baseArea);
            var newVerticalRes = (int)(img.Height / scaleFactor);
            var newHorizontalRes = (int)(img.Width / scaleFactor);
            var newImage = ResizeImage(img, new Size(newHorizontalRes, newVerticalRes));

            if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                File.Delete(imagePath);
            newImage.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error("errore scala foto : " + ex.Message);
        //if (Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StopOnException"]))
        throw new Exception("CheckResolution errore scala foto : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

here the loadSingle... function

```
public static ImageFromFile LoadSigleImageFromFile(string file)
{
    var ris = new ImageFromFile();
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    if (fileInfo.Name != "Thumbs.db")
        ris = (new ImageFromFile() { FileInfo = fileInfo });

    return ris;
}
```

Update ResizeImage function

```
 private static Image ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = (int)imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = (int)imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        b.SetResolution(imgToResize.HorizontalResolution, imgToResize.VerticalResolution);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Also, why are you indenting your brackets for the methods like that?  They should line up with the beginning of the method declaration.

Comment: Please work on creating [MCVE]. I bet you are trying to delete exactly the same file that is open for your `stream`

Comment: And, you should be using the `using` statement for disposable resources.

Comment: I haven't identified exactly what file you're trying to open twice, but the problem is almost certainly due to the fact that GDI `Image` objects (created by `Image.FromFile()`, etc.) keep their underlying streams open.  That is to say, `Image.FromFile(path)` will open a stream to the file at `path` that won't be closed until you dispose the image.

Comment: **ImageFromFile** doesn't seem to be a NET class. What happen here when you call that constructor could be the start of your problems

Comment: **ImageFromFile** {
public Stream Image ,
public FileInfo FileInfo}

Comment: @roryap plenty of programmers indent this way. Some find it much easier to quickly associate the closing bracket with the opening, since those characters sit on the same horizontal location.

Comment: @bradykey -- no, you're not understanding my comment.  Look at the initial post before it was edited.

Comment: @roryap ahaha you're right , i'm sorry :)

Comment: @roryap I see what you were commenting on now. Sorry about the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evident in your code that this block of lines

```
if (File.Exists(imagePath))
    File.Delete(imagePath);
```

tries to delete the same file opened by the Stream above. You should try to pospone the deletion of the file (and the following Save) only after the closing of the Stream opened before.

I could suggest these changes

```
public static void CheckResolution(string imagePath)
{      
    // Flag becomes true if the resize operation completes
    bool resizeCompleted = false;
    Image newImage = null;          

    // If file doesn't exist the code below returns null.
    var image = LoadSigleImageFromFile(imagePath);
    if(image == null) return;

    var baseArea = 2600 * 1000;//dimenzioni in risoluzione 
    using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(image.FileInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        try
        {
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            var imageArea = img.Height * img.Width;
            if (imageArea >= baseArea)
            {
                ... resize ops ....
                // if (File.Exists(imagePath))
                      //File.Delete(imagePath);
                // newImage.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                // Set the flag to true if resize completes
                resizeCompleted = true;
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("errore scala foto : " + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("CheckResolution errore scala foto : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Now you can delete and save....
    if(resizeCompleted)
    {
        // No need to check for existance. File.Delete doesn't throw if
        // the file doesn't exist
        File.Delete(imagePath);
        newImage.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}

public static ImageFromFile LoadSigleImageFromFile(string file)
{
    // Check if the file exists otherwise return null....
    var ris = null;
    if(File.Exists(file))
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        if (fileInfo.Name != "Thumbs.db")
           ris = (new ImageFromFile() { FileInfo = fileInfo });
    }
    return ris;
}
```

Moving the delete and save operations after the closing brace of the using block you are aure that the file is no more locked by your own program and you could proceed to the delete and save actions

Notice also that you should check for the existance of the input file before entering this code, otherwise an exception is here to wait for you.

Comment: in **Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);** i have another stream,
i'll have to dispose this stream too?

Comment: Did you get any errors? the stream is disposed at the exit from the using block so, no you don't need to dispose the stream instance